# What is the best way to organise geo-referenced data?

Tags: ios, algorithm, data-structures, tree, core-location

I have several locations each with a latitude and longitude and I need to find the closest location to a given point.  I can use Core location to find the distances from the point to the location but my algorithm is very inefficient (simply enumerating each location, computing the distance and keeping track of the lowest value).  Works fine for a few points but when you get to 100,000 things start to creak.

What is the best way to origanise the data so that I can quickly determine the closest location to a given point as well as whether a given location is within a specified rectangle?

I understand that gamers use tree structures to do quick collision testing but I am new to tree structures and wondered how to get started?  Are there any suitable tree structures in iOS or would I have to build my own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a kind of a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Organize your map in grids with increasing cell sizes.
If you look for near by points, look at the neighbor cells in the grid with the smallest cells, If you find none, search in the neighbor cells in the next coarser grid.

This is not perfect, because a grid always refers to [Manhatten distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) but you can get get good candidates for nearest points. For each candidate you than calculate the real  distance you are interested of.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but are there any implementations of a Quadtree within the iOS SDK or do you have to hand cut?

Comment: Found a implementation of a quadtree here http://erikolsson.me/articles/quadtrees-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to alter the structure after it is created and want it all to be in memory, i suggest [k-d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) tree. It is simple and fast, but adding new elements after the first bulk-load will disbalance it and the performance decreases.

If you want efficient adding and removing of elements, support for polygon elements or keeping the tree structure on disk, some variant of [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) would be better.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but are there any implementations of these types of trees within the iOS SDK or do you have to hand cut?